# B1/B2 visa application stuck on Pending Administrative Processing. What should I expect?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I have been granted 10-year B1/B2 visas twice previously. The second one expired in June 2017. On November 27, 2017, I applied for a new visa along with minor daughter’s visa application.

After a long interview, the visa officer informed us that our visa was refused, but technically our visa applications are pending. Surprisingly she kept our passports and told me to wait for an outcome within 2 days. Meanwhile, she gave me my payment slip and a 221(g) white slip without writing anything on it. She just marked the embassy’s email address for any additional contact.

Now tracking our visa applications online, I see they are in Administrative Processing (AP). After 2 weeks I emailed the embassy and they informed me that my case is still in pending AP. Once it's complete, they will inform me.

Does anyone have the same story? What is the reason for all that? Finally after AP did you get the visa or was it refused? Please share your experience or guide me why it’s happened to me.

Comment: Do you have a Muslim name? If that's the case it might take up to a month for the visas to be issued. However, normally they only issue AP for adult male applicants for security screening. They also do AP for other reasons such as involvement in certain tech fields. How many times have you previously traveled to the USA?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a request for anecdotes from people who were in a similar situation in the past. None of this will affect the outcome of the asker's visa application and the only thing to do is sit and wait.

Comment: adding to @DavidRicherby's VTC, all AP cases are unique and one cannot infer from other AP cases how yours will be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good read on the administrative processing:
https://www.immihelp.com/visas/221grefusal/administrative-processing-221g.html

I know a few friends who have had administrative processing for other VISA categories (H1). It has taken up to 4-5 weeks from my knowledge. Also, certain conditions by default put you under administrative processing. For e.g. :

1) Your Name
2) Your job description.

I am well aware that both the above reasons can get you in for background checks / administrative processing.

Since yours is a B1/B2 category VISA, there is no reason to worry till your administrative processing has come back with a decision.

Answer (score 0):

I was given 221(g) post my Visa interview (b1/b2) at Chennai stating it needs some additional processing. The office said he cannot commit on the timelines. He retained my passport too,

10-Sep-2018 - Interview followed by handing over of 221(g)
10-Sep-2018 - Status updated in the portal as "Administrative Processing"
14-Sep-2018 - Status Updated and still shown as "Administrative Processing"
20-Sep-2018 - Status updated and shown as "issued"
24-Sep-2018 - Received the passport today with 10 years of Visa stamped